# Trying subscript a column of tuple containing None values results in 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column full of tuples which i want to subscript into 2 separate columns. However some of the rows have a None value and thus unable to subscript the entire column.

```
0         None
1     (2, x1L)
2     (1, x1L)
3     (2, x4L)
4     (1, x4L)
        ...   
95    (1, x2L)
96    (1, x1L)
97    (2, x1L)
98    (6, x1L)
99    (6, x1L)
Name: order_1, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

If i try to fillna with empty tuples i get "Attempting to replace NaN with tuple, must be string or int"

then if i put a 0 or "" i get int or str not subscriptable

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, do you want to fill `None` values in column with a "dummy" tuple?

If you have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [None, (1, 'X1L'), (2, 'X2L'), None]})
print(df)

     Column
0      None
1  (1, X1L)
2  (2, X2L)
3      None
```

---

Then:

```
df.loc[df['Column'].isna(), 'Column'] = [('', '')]
```

Creates:

```
     Column
0      (, )
1  (1, X1L)
2  (2, X2L)
3      (, )
```

Comment: yes u understood me correctly this is the error im getting when trying your method 

ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Comment: @MarcHenrySaad Even my example isn't working as it is? What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: I dont think it's a python version issue. I tried to replicate your dataframe as it is above and it worked. But on my dataframe it gives the above mentioned error